Bazel (C++) link error - how to know which function is unresolved (Bazel does not tell this)?
I build a C++ project with Bazel on Linux using the command:
bazel build ...

And I get the following error message:
 INFO: Analyzed target //cpp/bin/operator:operator (0 packages loaded,
 0 targets configured). ERROR:
 my_project/BUILD:4:10: Linking
 cpp/bin/my_project failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error
 executing CppLink command (from target //cpp/bin/my_project:my_project)
 /home/my_user/.nix-profile/bin/gcc
 @bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/cpp/bin/my_project/my_project-2.params
 
 Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and
 retain the sandbox build root for debugging
 /nix/store/2b99rpx8zwdjjqkrvk7kqgn9mxhiidjy-binutils-2.38/bin/ld.gold:
 internal error in format_file_lineno, at dwarf_reader.cc:2713
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Target
 //cpp/bin/my_project:my_project failed to build Use --verbose_failures to
 see the command lines of failed build steps.

This is unresolved function problem - but how can I cause Bazel to print the name of the function which definition is missing?
Please help, I often have this error and it takes ages to find the missing function by commenting out parts of code and re-running the compilation command.
These flags do not help:
--verbose_failures
--sandbox_debug

I don't see any mention of an unresolved function or symbol in that output. There does seem to be an "internal error" in the linker itself, for unknown reasons. Have you tried using --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps? Then you could likely replicate the problem, and help understand what it might be.

Thank for your reply. I know this is unresolved, because when I add function definition in .cc file, the build succeeds.

Maybe the build succeeds because the corrupted file (guessing from the error message) is regenerated. Unresolved functions are not reported as an internal error.

In my bazelrc file I commented out the line:
#build --copt -g

And now it does show the details of the link error including the function which was not found.
